# Memoization with factorial in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, memoization

I wrote a Python module to learn about [*memoization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), and I have some questions on what I did.

- How *pythonic* is this?
- Does it make a difference if I used a class attribute instead of a function attribute for my `lookup_table`?
- How can I modify `multi_run_chrono` to use it like Python's decorators (with `@`)?
- Should I keep the `try... except KeyError` or rather do `if key in dictionary...`?
- Are there some nice tricks I could do to improve this code's elegance and/or performance?

Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from random import randint
from time import clock


def naive_factorial(n):
    """calculates n! with a simple recursive algorithm"""
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * naive_factorial(n-1)


def memo_factorial(n):
    """calculates n! using memoization in a recursive algorithm"""
    if not hasattr(memo_factorial, 'lookup_table'):
        memo_factorial.lookup_table = {0: 1}
    try:
        return memo_factorial.lookup_table[n]
    except KeyError:
        val = n * memo_factorial(n - 1)
        memo_factorial.lookup_table[n] = val
        return val


def check_correctness():
    print('Checking both functions do the same things')

    for i in [0, 1, 4, 10, 22, 63]:
        n = naive_factorial(i)
        m = memo_factorial(i)
        print('n = %d -- Naive : %d, Memo : %d' % (i, n, m))
        if n != m:
            print('Error in functions implementation')
            exit()


def multi_run_chrono(func, nb_runs, min_val, max_val):
    print('Running %s %d times, with n from %d to %d'
          % (func.__name__, nb_runs, min_val, max_val))
    tests = [randint(min_val, max_val) for _ in xrange(nb_runs)]
    starting_time = clock()
    for n in tests:
        func(n)
    ending_time = clock()
    print('Duration : %fs' % (ending_time - starting_time))


def main():
    # check_correctness()  # comment/uncomment to check or not
    for func in [naive_factorial, memo_factorial]:
        multi_run_chrono(func, 20000, 10, 200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Benchmarking on my computer :

```
Running naive_factorial 20000 times, with n from 10 to 200
Duration : 0.596933s
Running memo_factorial 20000 times, with n from 10 to 200
Duration : 0.006060s
```

All remarks are welcome, thank you very much!

Comment: That's a nice piece of code regarding PEP8 style guide. Good job. Nothing to comment on this part.

Comment: Consider updating to Python 3 where memoization is built-in `functools.lru_cache`, also consider separating the algoritmh from the memoization logic.

Comment: @Dex'ter thanks, this is not the first time I post here, glad to see I learned my lessons well.

Comment: @Caridorc I'll look it up thanks. By _separating the algoritmh from the memoization logic_, do you mean like decorating the `naive_factorial` to make it use memoization instead of creating a whole new function with memoization integrated?

Comment: @BusyAnt Exactly, so you can reuse the memoization capability with different functions.

Comment: @BusyAnt Graipher addresed this issue in his own answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding the memoization, here are two different ways to do this (for single-valued functions):

```
import functools

def memoize(func):
    cache = func.cache = {}

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(n):
        if n not in cache:
            cache[n] = func(n)
        return cache[n]
    return wrapper

def memodict(f):
    """ Memoization decorator for a function taking a single argument """
    class memodict(dict):
        def __missing__(self, key):
            ret = self[key] = f(key)
            return ret
    return memodict().__getitem__

@memodict
# @memoize
def factorial(n):
    """calculates n! with a simple recursive algorithm"""
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

The latter is faster because it saves one additional lookup, but only works for single-valued functions, whereas the first can be extended to also pass along multiple arguments.

The `memoize` is also nice, because it keeps the documentation of the function because of `functools.wraps` (try `help(factorial)` in both cases to see the difference).

Which implementation is faster depends on how often your `try` block misses and succeeds.

As for timings:
Using `@memoize` to calculate all factorials from 1 to 100000000 takes 2.66s on my machine, while doing the same with `@memodict` takes 2.51s, so not a big difference.

If you want to use a decorator to time the execution time of a function, this will not work very nicely here, since if you decorate `factorial`, every execution of the function will be timed (because of recursion this will be very often).

You can however use something like this:

```
def timeit(func, *args, **kwargs):
    starting_time = clock()
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    ending_time = clock()
    print 'Duration: {}'.format(ending_time - starting_time)
    return result

timeit(factorial, 100)
```

If you do want to use this as decorator, just insert a wrapper:

```
def timeit(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        starting_time = clock()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        ending_time = clock()
        print 'Duration: {}'.format(ending_time - starting_time)
        return result
    return wrapper

@timeit
def f():
    pass
```

Comment: I'm a big fan of your `memodict` implementation, but it should still be possible to use it with multiple-valued functions. You just need an extra level of indirection that takes the args & kwargs and turns them into a tuple (or something hashable) and uses that as a key.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I took the implementation from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578231-probably-the-fastest-memoization-decorator-in-the-/ where different ways to get it to work with multiple arguments are discussed. All take a small performance hit when applied to the special case of one argument, though.

Answer (score 2):

#### `check_correctness`

```
def check_correctness():
```

Functions should better take arguments to allow reuse, I would give the two functions and the inputs as arguments.

```
print('Checking both functions do the same things')
```

Unavoidable printing inside a function makes it impossible to reuse and violates the single responsability principle (computation + information)

```
for i in [0, 1, 4, 10, 22, 63]:
```

`i` is not descriptive you should use `testcase` to convey more information.

```
n = naive_factorial(i) 
m = memo_factorial(i)
```

After removing print there is no need for these temporary variables.

```
 print('n = %d -- Naive : %d, Memo : %d' % (i, n, m))
```

Remove as above.

```
if n != m:
    print('Error in functions implementation') exit()
```

Raise an exception instead to allow the caller to catch it if he wants (further increasing re-usability)